# Why isn't this timezone being set correctly?

Tags: java, android, timezone

Given the following (Android) code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().toString());
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().toString());
```

I get the following output:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

Why isn't my `America\New York` timezone being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));`
Not fully sure yet but I think a wrong timezone ID might be your problem.

See also: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: To clarify, the correction uses an underscore in "New York" for this: `America/New_York`. See this [list of proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer is correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356231/642706) The problem seems to be an incorrect [time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

## Joda-Time

FYI, here's the same kind of code in Joda-Time. In Joda-Time, a DateTime object knows its own assigned time zone unlike a java.util.Date object.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

Adjust to UTC if needed.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = now.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Convert to java.util.Date if needed for use with other classes.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```